# populating vector into map

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary

I´m trying to populate a Point map with a vector of Points. I´m trying to make a board game where each position on the board has a point (x,y) and vector of legal moves (Point objects).

I can´t seem to be able to have a map KEY as a Point.

```
struct Point
{
    Point() {}
    Point(int ix, int iy ) :x(ix), y(iy) {}

    int x;
    int y;
};


Point p_source (2,2);
Point p_next1 (1,2);
Point p_next2 (1,3);
Point p_next3 (1,4);

map <Point, vector<Point> > m_point;

dict[p_source].push_back(p_next1);
dict[p_source].push_back(p_next2);
dict[p_source].push_back(p_next3);
```

This is the errors that I get

> In member function 'bool std::less<_Tp>::operator()(const _Tp&, const
>   _Tp&) const [with _Tp = Point]':|
>
> instantiated from '_Tp& std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare,
>   _Alloc>::operator[](const _Key&) [with _Key = Point, _Tp = std::vector,
>   std::allocator >, std::allocator, std::allocator > > >, _Compare =
>   std::less, _Alloc = std::allocator,
>   std::allocator >, std::allocator, |
>
> instantiated from here|
>
> c:\program files ( no match for 'operator<' in '__x < __y'| ||===
>   Build finished: 1 errors, 0 warnings ===|

Answer (score 15):

Checking my favourite online reference [it reads](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map):

> ```
> template<
>     class Key,
>     class T,
>     class Compare = std::less<Key>,
>     class Allocator = std::allocator<std::pair<const Key, T> >
> > class map;
> ```
>
> Map is an associative container that contains a sorted list of unique
>   key-value pairs. **That list is sorted using the comparison function
>   `Compare` applied to the keys.** Search, removal, and insertion operations
>   have logarithmic complexity. Maps are usually implemented as red-black
>   trees.

Since you don't provide an explicit `Compare` it sorts using the default `std::less<Key>`. Seems like we're on the right track because the errors are in that class:

> In member function 'bool std::less<_Tp>::operator()(const _Tp&, const
>   _Tp&) const [with _Tp = Point]':|

Let's [check that](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less):

> ```
> template< class T >
> struct less;
> ```
>
> Function object for performing comparisons. Uses `operator<` on type `T`.

This matches what the error messages tell us:

> no match for 'operator<' in '__x < __y'

Hmm, but there's no `operator<` for type `Point`...

Answer (score 8):

Your error is entirely unrelated to `std::vector<>` – *`std::map<>`* requires that its key either be comparable with `operator<`, or that you supply a custom comparitor. The easiest solution is to add the following after `Point`'s definition:

```
bool operator <(Point const& lhs, Point const& rhs)
{
    return lhs.y < rhs.y || lhs.y == rhs.y && lhs.x < rhs.x;
}
```